# JAR Could not find resource file

Tags: java, jar

I build a package, then add it to another application library, and it works fine. But if I move the project with the built package in another folder. The one with added `JAR` could not run. I build the project again, delete the old JAR from the library and add the new, but it still search the JAR in the old path and gives me "`Could not find resource file`".
The link to the problem in the code leads to

```
 <copy todir="${dist.dir}${file.separator}lib" flatten="true"   
   preservelastmodified="true" overwrite="true">
```

What can I do to make it follow the new path to the JAR instead of the old location?

Answer (score 0):

Please Verify your SDK Manager / Import New SDK Manager and restart your IDE It Worked for me in **Eclipse**.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't help. I am working with NetBeans 8.2.